# How to run silent installer in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, silent-installer

I have the following C# code:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c" + desktopPath + "\\" + "MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe –s –v –qn");
```

The first line gets the path of my desktop where the .exe is located. The string `desktopPath` is used in the second line.

The second line is ***supposed*** to start the installer in silent mode, so that the process runs in the background and the installation wizard does NOT appear at all. Running the string result of `desktopPath + "\\" + "MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe –s –v –qn"` in the command prompt works just fine, and the installer runs in silent mode. In case anyone is wondering, the string result of

`desktopPath + "\\" + "MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe –s –v –qn"`

is

`C:\Users\ME\Desktop\MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe -s -v -qn`

and running this in the command prompt runs the installation in silent mode.

Unfortunately, triggering the same command in C# code as this:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c" + desktopPath + "\\" + "MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe –s –v –qn");
```

does not run the installer in silent mode. Instead, the wizard comes up, visible to the user.

Does anyone know how I can modify this:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c" + desktopPath + "\\" + "MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe –s –v –qn");
```

so that the installer actually runs in silent mode, without the installer UI showing??

**SIDE NOTE: –s –v –qn are switches for running in silent mode.**

Comment: Try moving all of the flags up before the name of the executable.

Comment: @Amy, before the executable, where?

Comment: @Amy, if you mean where the /C is then I've already tried that.

Comment: If you surround your command with quotes does it work? `"/c \"" + desktopPath + "\\" + "MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe –s –v –qn\""`, so you should end up with the string `/c "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe -s -v -qn"` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.Arguments = "–s –v –qn";
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.FileName = "MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe";
Process.Start(psi);
```

I don't know if the arguments you provided tried to hide the window, but perhaps like this, part of it won't be neccesary anymore.

Note that I used "notepad.exe" for my tests which were successful. Perhaps your installer reacts differently.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, the window still appears when I try your code above. Nice try though.

Comment: @Zolt is the -s switch suppose to mean "silent" ?

Comment: Try removing it (-s) perhaps it somehow conflicts. If that does not work, try commenting out the WindowStyle line.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the installer directly:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string installerPath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe");
Process.Start(installerPath, "–s –v –qn");
```

Comment: This is s good try, but the installer UI still shows up when I try it. Not sure why. It's like the switches are being ignored for some reason.